# combine custom search form and searchresult

Tags: search

What is the best way to implement a single page with a:
- search part
- search result
- display form if no result is found

Any samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the existing Search Center templates for this?

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556856.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but i can't find much info. The top op my page should contain a 'checkbox form' to ex/include specific parts of information in the searchresult. The bottom of the page should contain the searchresult,  (refreshed with ajax). The XSLT of the searchresult will handle the 'no result option' (thanks to mike for that tip)

Comment: To be able to create a search site you need to activate a feature called something like "SharePoint Search Enterprise feature" (cant remember the exact name right now). Then create a Search center. Then go to Site Settings > Search settings to point your search box to that search center and set other search related settings

Answer (score 0):

All of the web parts used on the search center pages are available for other pages.  The best way to provide feedback when no results are found is to change the XSL in the result web part.  There is a section for formatting that message and it is easiest to find by searching for the message.